# Obtaining maximun _key value from an Arango Collection

Tags: python, collections, arangodb, python-arango

Imagine that `_key` is a series which is always increasing, such as:

```
{
  _key:1,
  name: John,
  ...
},
{
  _key:2,
  name ...
},
...
```

I would like to get the maximum value of `_key` so I can include another element with a `_key + 1` value.

I am using `python-arango` but I could collect the AQL query too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Some kind of reaction would be appreciated - is the aql snippet I provided helpful, or did I misunderstand you, ...?

Answer (score 0):

To get the largest numerical `_key` value of collection `coll` so far:

```
      FOR c IN coll
        COLLECT AGGREGATE maxk = MAX(c._key)
        RETURN {max_coll_key: TO_NUMBER(maxk)}
```